# Recover programmation source files

Tags: linux, data-recovery, grep, regex, reiserfs

I've source code files (Java and C++) to recover from a broken RAID 1+0 array, I've been able to access the virtual drive with an other server but the ReiserFS partition can't be recovered with ReiserFS tools.

I've made a binary image of the partition using DD, now I'm wondering if there is a tool better than GREP to find files using tags contained in files ex.:

WatchDog.cpp that must contain "class WatchDog..."

```
grep -a -B20 -A1000 'class WatchDog' BACKUP.img | strings > recovered.txt
```

I was thinking about some kind of REGEX tool that can find these files with a pattern as this is programming code!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

if you get desperate try http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec , i've had success with this program. Also http://trinityhome.org/Home/blog.php?front_id=15 might have some tools you can use.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Even if the partition cannot be recovered, can it still be mounted? What happens if you try something like `mount -t reiserfs -o ro,loop your_dd_image.img /mnt/recovery`? Does the mount fail? I also once experienced a failing RAID array containing a ReiserFS file system. In my case the partition contained lots of errors and was more like a fail system instead of file system, but nevertheless I was able to recover lots of files from there and the rest from the backups (you have those, right? ;).

Comment: failsystem -> filesytem :-) hah, that's almost as a good as network   -> notwork.